# Group of order 27

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a group of order 27. Let $x\in G/Z(G)$ where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$. Then what is the possible orders of the centralizer of $x$ and what is the number of conjugates of $x$?

Any hint or idea will be appreciated. I am really stuck.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have shown that if G is not abelian then we must have G/Z(G) is of order 9.

Comment: Hint: Any group of order $p^2$ is abelian where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Do you mean $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$?

Comment: If $x\notin Z(G)$ then its centraliser is bigger than $Z(G)$ but smaller than $G$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities, $|Z(G)|=1$ or 3. In both cases, $G/Z(G)$ is abelian. The centralizer of $x$ has order $27$ in the first case and $9$ in the second case, and its conjugacy class consists of $x$ alone in both cases.